# Mail pops up frequently

Tags: macos, mail.app

Apple mail application often appears and asks me to enter email address and password.
I don't use this application.
It happens even though I never clicked email address or something like that.
How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Steps you can take to ensure this doesn't happen:

1. Make sure that Mail.app isn't set to open at login.
2. Check your Mail, Contacts & Calendars settings to make sure you don't have an invalid account linked to your Mail account.
3. If you don't use the app, make sure you actually Quit the app instead of closing the application window (that's a common mistake for new Mac users).